# session management for entire application iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am getting connecting with restful web services, on login i get this session id.

```
"session":"86da8a2cb82ff46595bf2d8a57875e03"
```

After login once, this session id would be used to get the data from web services for other views of the application.

How can i make it global so that if there is change in session value global variable's value also gets changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the session id to only last while the application is open you can use a **global variable**. If you want your session id to last longer you can store it in the [user defaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

**example:**

```
// global variable
static NSString * sessionIDStore = nil;

+ (NSString*)sessionID {
    return sessionIDStore;
}

+ (void)setSessionID:(NSString*)newSessionID {
    [newSessionID retain];
    [sessionIDStore release];
    sessionIDStore = newSessionID;
}

// user defaults
+ (NSString*)sessionID {
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myapp.sessionID"];
}

+ (void)setSessionID:(NSString*)newSessionID {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newSessionID forKey:@"myapp.sessionID"];
}
```

if you use `NSUserDefaults` remember to call `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` when your app is about to exit.

Comment: Its ok ... i have got the idea now I can do it :)

Answer (score 4):

I am also doing an ipad app for a web-service using web API's.

When you send a request using NSHttpRequest it will automatically save those cookies and will send those info/cookies alongwith any further web-service URL requests. It is done by NSHttpCookieStorage based on the cookie storage policy. By default this policy is NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyAlways. Hence it may not necessary to have the session-id in a global variable.

For better understanding go through apple's documentation on [**URL Loading System**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html). Especially **URL Loading System Overview** -> **Cookie Storage** section.

When you log-out or session expires you have to handle manually, i.e, remove those cookies from the NSHttpCookie and show a log-in screen.

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
for (cookie in [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] cookies]) 
{
    [[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] deleteCookie:cookie];
}
```

I hope as per this design you no need to store the session-id as a global variable.

This is how my iPad application works.

Comment: thanx durai... can you please refer me to any tutorial link for nshttpcookie

Comment: I will recommend you to go through the apple document that I have referred. It has given related classes and link to the corresponding documentation.

Comment: Good point NSHttpRequest,NSHttpCookieStorage,NSHttpCookieAcceptPolicyAlways